# How to make a frame fill the entire available space, and the widget inside it to stick to the left side

Tags: user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to have a frame that fills the entire screen from left to right (because of the border relief) and the widgets inside it to stick to the left side. But when I put `-sticky nswe` on the frame and `-sticky nsw` on the widgets themselves, the frame takes the entire window, but the widgets are aligned to the left of the **center** of the frame and not to the left-most side of it:

[image]

and I want it to look like (created with paint):

[image]

And the code creating it is (for the upper frame, with the file extentions):

**EDIT:** added more of the code, and fixed the numbering issue of the columns and rows

```
proc eyes_view_create_file_extention_bar {frm_main listOfPossibleExtensions} {
    #Files Extention Bar
    set files_cb ::eyes_view_file_ext_arr_cb
    grid [set file_frm [frame $frm_main.file_frm -relief groove -bd 2]] -row 0 -column 0 -columnspan 2 -sticky nswe
    set file_lbl [label $file_frm.lbl -text "File Extenctions to Show:"]
    set columns 0
    foreach file_ext $listOfPossibleExtensions {
        set cb [checkbutton $file_frm.[regsub -all {\.} $file_ext {}] -text $file_ext -variable ${files_cb}(${file_ext}) -command [list _eyes_view_update]]
        set ${files_cb}(${file_ext}) 0
        grid $cb -row 1 -column $columns -sticky wsn
        incr columns
    }
    grid $file_lbl -row 0 -columnspan $columns -sticky wsn    
}

proc eyes_view_main_widget {base listOfExternalVarsAndValues listOfPossibleExtensions} {

    wm title $base "Eyes Viewer"
    array set [set files_cb ::eyes_view_file_ext_arr_cb] {}
    array set [set vars_cb ::eyes_view_vars_arr_cb] {}
    set frm_main [frame  $base.main_frm]
    pack $frm_main -expand 1 -fill both

    #graph
    set g_frm [frame $frm_main.graph]
    grid $g_frm -row 2 -column 1 -sticky nsew
    set g [eyes_graph_widget $frm_main.graph graph]
    #splits table

    grid [set split_frm [frame  $frm_main.tbl_split]] -row 2 -column 0 -sticky nswe
    set apply_button    [button $split_frm.apply -text "Apply" -command [list _eyes_view_update]]
    set split_tbl_frm   [frame  $split_frm.tbl_frm]

    set split_table [sparam_table_widget $split_tbl_frm split_table]

    #file extensions frame, vars frame & legend
    set file_frm [eyes_view_create_file_extention_bar $frm_main $listOfPossibleExtensions]
    set var_frm  [eyes_view_create_vars_values_bar $frm_main $listOfExternalVarsAndValues]
    set legend_frm [eyes_view_create_legend_frame $frm_main]

    grid $split_tbl_frm -row 0 -sticky nwse
    grid $apply_button  -row 1 -sticky nwse

    grid columnconfigure $frm_main 0 -weight 0
    grid columnconfigure $frm_main 1 -weight 1
    grid rowconfigure    $frm_main 0 -weight 0
    grid rowconfigure    $frm_main 1 -weight 0
    grid rowconfigure    $frm_main 2 -weight 1
    grid rowconfigure    $frm_main 3 -weight 0

    grid rowconfigure    $split_frm 0 -weight 1
    grid rowconfigure    $split_frm 1 -weight 0
    ...
    return [list $g $split_table $legend_frm $frm_main]
}
```

Comment: I could not figure out what you are trying to do. How different the result should be from what the picture shows now?

Comment: why are you using column and row indexes starting from 1, try starting from 0

Comment: @Ashot, that's what I always used, I changed it to start from 0, it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not reproduce your problem. After I fixed all the variables I got exactly the behavior you want. Maybe it's because this is not a complete script and there is something going on in what's left out. Anyway try the following:

Change

```
grid $file_frm -row 1 -column 1 -columnspan 2 -sticky nswe
```

to

```
grid $file_frm -row 1 -column 1 -columnspan 2 -sticky nswe
grid anchor $file_frm w
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the parent window ($frm_main) how you want it to propagate geometry changes to its children. In this case you probably want:

```
grid columnconfigure $frm_main 1 -weight 1
grid rowconfigure $frm_main 1 -weight 1
```

which says to give new space to row 1 column 1 when the parent size changes. It is worth reading the documentation on this quite carefully and using some simple frames with different colours (frame .f -background red and so on) to get a good idea of how grid works.

Your array handling is broken in the example too. The -variable option takes a variable name so you just want `-variable files_cb($file_ext)` and you don't want to dereference when trying to set the array value either. Try `set files_cb($file_ext) 0` instead.

Comment: `files_cb` is a value that holds the full name of the array which is long and I wanted a shortcut, so `set ${file_cb}($file_ext) 0` actualy sets the value of `::eyes_view_file_ext_arr_cb($file_ext)" to 0

Comment: And, I'm already giving the rows and columns of `frm_main` weights in another section of the code, so that is not the answer, please see the added code in the edit.